# why do i get this mysql error messages

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to install an e-learning application but when i get to the part that i enter my mysql details, even though i enterred the right details i get these error

```
***Looks like there have been some errors with inserting data into your database!
You cannot continue.***
```

Below is the error log I pull out.

```
SQL=Too big precision 14 specified for column 'updated'. Maximum is 6.:
- - - - - - - - - -
################# Users ##############################
# Table structure for table `tbl_users`

    CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
      id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      userId varchar(25) NOT NULL default '0',
      username varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
      title varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
      firstName varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
      surname varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
      PASSWORD varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      creationDate date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
      emailAddress varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      logins int(11) default '0',
      sex char(1) default '',
      country char(2) default '',
      accesslevel char(1) default '0',
      isActive CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1',
      howCreated VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT 'unknown',
      updated timestamp(14),
      PRIMARY KEY  (id),
      INDEX userId (userId)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB  COMMENT='Primary user information'
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_users' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_users (id,userId,username,title,firstName,surname,PASSWORD,creationDate,emailAddress,logins,sex,country,accessLevel,isActive,howCreated) VALUES ('init_1','1', 'admin', 'Dr', 'Administrative', 'User', '86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8', '0000-00-00', 'admin@localhost.local', 0, 'M', 'ZA','1','1','install');
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB  ROW_FORMAT=FIXED COMMENT='Used to hold the loginhistory of a user'' at line 7:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_userloginhistory` (
      `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      `userId` char(25) NOT NULL default '0',
      `lastLoginDateTime` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
      KEY `userId` (`userId`)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB  ROW_FORMAT=FIXED COMMENT='Used to hold the loginhistory of a user';
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB  COMMENT='This table is used to maintain state and enable communicat' at line 15:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    #
    #

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_loggedinusers` (
       id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `userId` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '0',
      `ipAddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      `sessionId` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      `whenLoggedIn` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `WhenLastActive` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `isInvisible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      `coursecode` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      `themeUsed` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB  COMMENT='This table is used to maintain state and enable communication';
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB' at line 18:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    ################################# Modules ##############################3

    # Table structure for table `tbl_modules`

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_modules` (
       id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      module_id varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
      module_authors text,
      module_releasedate datetime default NULL,
      module_version varchar(20) default NULL,
      module_path varchar(255) default NULL,
      isAdmin tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      isVisible tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
      hasAdminPage tinyint(1) default '1',
      isContextAware tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      dependsContext tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB;
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 10:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    #
    #

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_modules_dependencies` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `module_id` varchar(50) default NULL,
      `dependency` varchar(50) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
      KEY `id` (`dependency`)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB' at line 8:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_modules_owned_tables` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `kng_module` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0',
      `tablename` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
      KEY `tbl_kng_modules_owned_tables_FKIndex1` (`kng_module`),
      KEY `kng_module` (`kng_module`)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='Table to hold system types for text abstraction'' at line 14:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    ################################# Systext ##############################3

    # Table structure for table `tbl_systext_system`

    CREATE TABLE tbl_systext_system(
        id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        systemType VARCHAR(15) NULL,
        creatorId VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        dateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL,
        canDelete TINYTEXT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        KEY(creatorId),
        CONSTRAINT `Systext_system_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorId`) REFERENCES `tbl_users` (`userId`)
        ) TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='Table to hold system types for text abstraction'
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    # Data for `tbl_systext_system`

    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_1', 'default', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_2', 'elearn', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_3', 'groups', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_4', 'workgroups', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_5', 'pgrad', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_6', 'alumni', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_system' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_system(id, systemType, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_7', 'content', '1', '0000-00-00');
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='List of text items to be abstracted'' at line 14:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    ################################# Systext ##############################3

    # Table structure for table `tbl_systext_text`

    CREATE TABLE tbl_systext_text(
        id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        text VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        creatorId VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        dateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL,
        canDelete TINYTEXT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        KEY(creatorId),
        CONSTRAINT `Systext_text_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorId`) REFERENCES `tbl_users` (`userId`)
        ) TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='List of text items to be abstracted'
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    # Data for `tbl_systext_text`

    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_1', 'context', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_2', 'contexts', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_3', 'author', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_4', 'authors', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_5', 'organisation', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_6', 'organisations', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_7', 'readonly', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_8', 'readonlys', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_9', 'workgroup', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_10', 'workgroups', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_11', 'story', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_text' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_text(id, text, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_12', 'stories', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N');
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='List of text items to be abstracted'' at line 22:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    ################################# Systext ##############################3

    # Table structure for table `tbl_systext_abstract`

    CREATE TABLE tbl_systext_abstract(
        id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        systemId VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        textId VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        abstract VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        creatorId VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        dateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL,
        canDelete TINYTEXT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        KEY(systemId),
        KEY(textId),
        KEY(creatorId),
        CONSTRAINT `Systext_abstract_system` FOREIGN KEY (`systemId`) REFERENCES `tbl_systext_system` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT `Systext_abstract_text` FOREIGN KEY (`textId`) REFERENCES `tbl_systext_text` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT `Systext_abstract_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorId`) REFERENCES `tbl_users` (`userId`)
        ) TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='List of text items to be abstracted'
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    # Data for `tbl_systext_abstract`

    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_1', 'init_1', 'init_1', 'course', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_2', 'init_1', 'init_2', 'courses', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_3', 'init_1', 'init_3', 'lecturer', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_4', 'init_1', 'init_4', 'lecturers', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_5', 'init_1', 'init_5', 'organisation', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_6', 'init_1', 'init_6', 'organisations', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_7', 'init_1', 'init_7', 'student', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_8', 'init_1', 'init_8', 'students', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_9', 'init_1', 'init_9', 'workgroup', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_10', 'init_1', 'init_10', 'workgroups', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_11', 'init_1', 'init_11', 'story', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated, canDelete)
        values('init_12', 'init_1', 'init_12', 'stories', '1', '0000-00-00', 'N')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_13', 'init_2', 'init_1', 'course', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_14', 'init_2', 'init_2', 'courses', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_15', 'init_2', 'init_3', 'lecturer', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_16', 'init_2', 'init_4', 'lecturers', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_17', 'init_2', 'init_5', 'organisation', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_18', 'init_2', 'init_6', 'organisations', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_19', 'init_2', 'init_7', 'student', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_20', 'init_2', 'init_8', 'students', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_21', 'init_2', 'init_9', 'workgroup', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_22', 'init_2', 'init_10', 'workgroups', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_23', 'init_2', 'init_11', 'story', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_24', 'init_2', 'init_12', 'stories', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_25', 'init_3', 'init_1', 'group', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_26', 'init_3', 'init_2', 'groups', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_27', 'init_3', 'init_3', 'group author', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_28', 'init_3', 'init_4', 'group authors', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_29', 'init_3', 'init_7', 'readonly member', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_30', 'init_3', 'init_8', 'readonly members', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_31', 'init_4', 'init_1', 'workgroup', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_32', 'init_4', 'init_2', 'workgroups', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_33', 'init_4', 'init_3', 'workgroup author', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_34', 'init_4', 'init_4', 'workgroup authors', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_35', 'init_4', 'init_7', 'workgroup user', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_36', 'init_4', 'init_8', 'workgroup users', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_37', 'init_5', 'init_1', 'supervision unit', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_38', 'init_5', 'init_2', 'supervision units', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_39', 'init_5', 'init_3', 'supervisor', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_40', 'init_5', 'init_4', 'supervisors', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_41', 'init_5', 'init_7', 'student', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_42', 'init_5', 'init_8', 'students', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_43', 'init_6', 'init_1', 'alumni group', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_44', 'init_6', 'init_2', 'alumni groups', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_45', 'init_6', 'init_3', 'content author', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =

    SQL=Table 'acquahadmin.tbl_systext_abstract' doesn't exist:
    - - - - - - - - - -
    INSERT INTO tbl_systext_abstract(id, systemId, textId, abstract, creatorId, dateCreated)
        values('init_46', 'init_6', 'init_4', 'content authors', '1', '0000-00-00')
    = = = = = = = = = =
```

Comment: The log gives you a clear message, why you receive this error. `14` is a too big precision for `timestamp` according to your dbms

Answer (score 3):

As the error message tells you, you have a too big precision set on the timestamp, the maximum is 6.

Change

```
updated timestamp(14),
```

to

```
updated timestamp(6),
```

or

```
updated timestamp(),
```